# How do I use grpcio-tools/ grpc_tools.protoc for relative imports in proto file

Tags: protocol-buffers, grpc-python

Say you have your dependent external interfaces for a service called `crane` under `\interaces\crane` folder like below

```
--interfaces
-----crane
------- crane.proto
------- vehicle.proto
```

And in crane.proto which is an external proto, you have this relative reference to vehicle proto

```
import crane/vehicle.proto
....
```

How do I use grpc_tools to generate the proto buffers for python binding correctly?

Using the below gives an error in crane.proto that vehicles.proto is not found

```
$(PYTHON) -m grpc_tools.protoc -I ./interfaces/crane --python_out=./my_proj/generated -- \
grpc_python_out=./my_proj/generated crane.proto
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use like below
https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/9575#issuecomment-293934506

```
build:

$(MKDIR) -p myproj/generated
touch myproj/generated/__init__.py
$(MKDIR) -p ndn_objtrack/myproj/crane
touch myproj/generated/crane/__init__.py

$(PYTHON) -m grpc_tools.protoc -I ./interfaces/ --python_out=./my_proj/generated -- \
grpc_python_out=./my_proj/generated crane/crane.proto
```

And to use in your Python file

```
import grpc

from generated.myproj import crane_pb2
from generated.myproj import crane_pb2_grpc
```